# Having image instead of writing numbers of a table

Tags: tables, elsarticle

In  one column "elsarticle" style, is it possible to add a picture instead of filling the numbers of a table and have captions over that picture for having style of a table?

Answer (score 1):

You asked,

> is it possible to add a picture instead of filling the numbers of a table ...?

The short answer: Yes.

The slightly longer answer: Let's assume the image of the table you wish to display resides in a file called `mytable.pdf`. Then all you need to do is (a) load the `graphicx` package in the preamble and (b) replace the `tabular` (or `tabular*`, or `tabularx`) environment with the instruction

```
\includegraphics[width=<desired width>]{mytable}
```

where `<desired width>` could be `\textwidth`, say. Everything else, such as `\begin{table}`, `\caption`, `\label` and `\end{table}`, can stay the same.